# How to get the chart equation and the R-squared value in Python Prophet (Facebook)

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I've been looking for a way to get the chart equation and the R-squared value using Facebook Prophet in Python. I'm trying to do something similar to what you do in Ms Excel (see example below).

[image]

I know Prophet includes a package named "utilities", however I don't know how to get my model's equation for slope, intercept and R-squared value.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: @itprorh66 What is opinion-based about this question? Also, keep in mind the MRE/MCVE requirement is only for questions about existing code that has a problem (e.g. debugging questions), not 'how to' questions.

Comment: "I've been looking for a way to get the chart equation and the R-squared value using Facebook Prophet in Python. I'm trying to do something similar to what you do in Ms Excel " is asking for our opinion on how to best do something.  Also, would like to point out, that debugging is outside the scope of StackOverflow without the minimal reproducible Example

Comment: Hi @TylerH I have the same question, I don't see how my question leads to subjective approaches.

Comment: @itprorh66 By that logic, _any_ question asking how to do something is asking for our 'opinion' on how to do it. This is also not a debugging question. Debugging questions are "I have this code and it doesn't work. Why not". Please familiarize yourself with the site via the [help] a bit more before applying inaccurate close reasons/leaving inaccurate comments for users.

Comment: @itprorh66 mh question doesn't ask for an opinion at all. I'm just asking if fhere's a function that does what I'm trying to achieve, not if there's a best way to do something. This is clearly not an example of debugging at all.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for clarifying the point. Do you know if there's any link or way to report this? It seems he doesn't have much experience with this.